# Facebook application refresh automatically

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My application refreshs automatically to facebook login url but my user already signed in so repeats refresh, nonstop.

Here is my code

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'my app id',
    'secret' => 'my secret key',
    'cookie' => true,
));
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$fbme = null;
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'canvas'    => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'next' => 'my app uri',
        'cancel_url' => 'my app uri',
        'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update,offline_access,user_birthday'
    )
);
if (!$session) {
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
   exit;
}
else {
  try {
      $uid      =   $facebook->getUser();
      $fbme     =   $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
      exit;
  }
}
function d($d){
return TRUE;
}
```

And my page's source in refresh is:

```
"<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = 'facebook login url..';</script>
```

Always refreshs, non stop.

I looked google and i found p3p policy: `header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');`
added but not working :(

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to look at this [document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/):

> **Cookies in iframes/P3P Header**
>   Some browsers will let iframes set cookies
>   based on the presence of the P3P
>   header. Notably, IE respects this
>   header. Ideally you may want to look
>   up the right value based on the
>   privacy policy adopted by your
>   application, but any value will
>   usually suffice. The sample
>   application sends this for instance:

```
P3P: CP="HONK"
```

Comment: Lol its your 3. answer to my questions and 3/3 best answer :) You are hero. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest version of the PHP-Sdk form My Apps -> your application
2. Disable the option Stream post URL security in My App->your application->Edit Settings.

You might be using the old version of the PHP Sdk.