# Facebook Custom IFrame Tabs and Internet Explorer 8 Issue

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, iframe, tabs

I have created my first IFrame App in facebook (custom tab), and all the IFrame is directing to is a simple PHP page, with HTML tags stating Hello World...

However, this is showing up in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer - and I cannot figure out why; even tried googling it to no avail.

Please help me! I cannot move forward without solving this issue!!

Comment: *Maybe* this is related:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083484/facebook-application-refresh-automatically/5083678#5083678

Answer (score 0):

did you already fixed this? I figured out that the Internet Explorer has a differend handling for parameters. I faced the same issue: my cutom tab (iframe) was working perfectly on Firefox, Opera, Chrome, but never shown IN IE7+8.

Later I realized that I added a questionmark to the URL, but w/o any parameter, like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/mypage.html?
```

Solution: If you just only want to embedd an html page, you don't need to do this any longer. Just create your Facebook app, go to "Facebook Integration", scroll down to "Page Tabs", add a "Tab Name" and the "Tab URL". Don't add a "?" to the Tab URL.

Once I removed the "?" the custom iframe tab is shown in Internet Explorer 7 and 8.