# Iframe facebook application redirecting problem on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-8, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a so strange problem in my app.
My app is iframe app performs Facebook authentication through OAuth in c#. 
It works fine on every browser except IE8, it sometimes works fine and sometimes does loop redirecting.
this is my app link: http://apps.facebook.com/gcmobile/ 
any idea, please?

Comment: There are no `urgent` questions on SO - most questions will get an answer quickly anyway unless they are poorly worded, unclear or horribly formatted. So please refrain from putting "URGENT" in the subject.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083484/facebook-application-refresh-automatically/5083678#5083678) might be related.