# facebook js login page keeps reloading in IE10

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, reload

I have implemented a simple facebook login script for my facebook page tab app. It supposes to authenticate the app to the user. It works fine in all browsers, but IE (I have IE10 for testing the compatibility). In IE it brings the authentication pop-up as it intended and user can authenticate it just fine, but then instead of opening the main app page (liked.php) as it does in other browsers it keeps reloading itself (login.php). I know no one should be using IE in our days, but some people does and I need it to work even for them:)
Thank you! The code is here:

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:login-button size="medium" onlogin="login()" scope="email, user_birthday">Logga in med Facebook</fb:login-button>
<script>
  // Additional JS functions here
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'myid', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//www.mydomain.com/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional init code here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // connected

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // not_authorized
      //login();
    } else {
      // not_logged_in
      //login();
    }
   });

  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

   function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
            window.location = 'liked.php';
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is the answer to my problem which as I noticed most Facebook connect solutions for tab apps (iframe in FB) have in IE10:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7083831/2169059